# No Space Zend Validator Regex

Tags: regex, zend-framework

What is the Regex that allows everything but spaces.
i tried this validator and other similar ones

```
 'validators' => array(
            array('regex', true,
                array(
                    'pattern'=>'/[^\s]/',
                    'messages'=>array(
                        'regexNotMatch'=>'Your own custom error message'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

I am using Zend Framework 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation seems to fail because it accepts any string with only one non-space caracter.

For example, these strings are accepted

```
 * 'hello world'  
 * 'a             b'  
 * '       c          '
```

You need to change your pattern to :

```
'pattern' => '/^[^\s]*$/'
```

If you need only alpha-numeric caracters, `Zend`

has already a built-in Alpha-Numeric validator

```
'validators' => array(
    array(
        'Alnum', 
        true,
        array('allowWhiteSpace' => false)
    )
)
```

Hope it helps